# "'For' is a reserved keyword." error in robot framework (RIDE tool)

Tags: python, for-loop, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Im unable to run the FOR keyword in robot framework, as im getting an error "'For' is a reserved keyword"

My script is as below:

```
*** Test Cases ***
forloop method 1
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${row}
        Log    ${i}
    END
```

My pip list is below:

```
Package                                 Version
--------------------------------------- -----------
-ymongo                                 3.10.1
backports.functools-lru-cache           1.6.1
beautifulsoup4                          4.8.2
cassandra-driver                        3.12.0
certifi                                 2019.11.28
chardet                                 3.0.4
decorator                               4.4.1
et-xmlfile                              1.0.1
futures                                 3.3.0
idna                                    2.8
jdcal                                   1.4.1
jsonpatch                               1.24
jsonpointer                             2.0
natsort                                 6.2.0
numpy                                   1.16.6
openpyxl                                2.6.4
Pillow                                  6.2.2
pip                                     19.3.1
Pygments                                2.5.2
pymongo                                 3.10.1
PyMySQL                                 0.9.3
PyPubSub                                3.3.0
pywin32                                 227
requests                                2.22.0
robotframework                          3.0.2
robotframework-cassandracqllibrary      1.0.0
robotframework-databaselibrary          1.2.4
robotframework-excellibrary             0.0.2
robotframework-extendedselenium2library 0.9.2
robotframework-httplibrary              0.4.2
robotframework-mongodblibrary           0.3.4
robotframework-requests                 0.6.2
robotframework-ride                     1.7.4
robotframework-selenium2library         1.8.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary          4.1.0
robotframework-SikuliLibrary            1.0.8
robotframework-stringformat             0.1.8
selenium                                3.8.1
setuptools                              41.2.0
six                                     1.13.0
soupsieve                               1.9.5
thrift                                  0.13.0
urllib3                                 1.25.7
waitress                                1.4.2
WebOb                                   1.8.5
WebTest                                 2.0.33
wxPython                                4.0.7.post2
xlrd                                    1.2.0
xlutils                                 2.0.0
xlwt                                    1.3.0
```

Please support, thanks in advance!
Do let me know if anything required from my end.

Comment: I was able to run your test case (ofc, added `${row}` variable) without errors using Robot Framework 3.1.2.

Comment: yes, my version robot framework was 3.0.2, now it is fine, thank u so much :)

Answer (score 5):

According to the Robot Framework documentation on [FOR Loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops) the `:FOR` syntax was in use till 3.x when the `FOR   END` construct was introduced.

Try:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Forloop method
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${row}
    \    Log    ${i}
```

Comment: Hi luigigi, :FOR does not work for my version. it says ERROR: Data sanity check failed.

Comment: @HimaManae are you sure the error relates to `:FOR`?

Comment: YES, when i save it, it will format back to FOR from :FOR and my script only contains this for loop method.

Comment: reserved.py file:RESERVED_KEYWORDS = ['for', 'while', 'break', 'continue', 'end',
                     'if', 'else', 'elif', 'else if', 'return']


class Reserved(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def get_keyword_names(self):
        return RESERVED_KEYWORDS

    def run_keyword(self, name, args):
        error = "'%s' is a reserved keyword." % name.title()
        if name in ('else', 'else if'):
            error += (" It must be in uppercase (%s) when used as a marker"
                      " with 'Run Keyword If'." % name.upper())
        raise Exception(error)

Comment: @HimaManae because I checked it and `:FOR` is used in version 3.0.4. It sounds more like there is an "unevaluable" character in a variable or sth. or an invisible character

Comment: @HimaManae not really. you can check if there are tabs instead of whitespaces first

Comment: @HimaManae and remove the `1` in that test case name

Comment: @HimaManae did you try a "Hello World" example? did it work?

Comment: yes have tried and it worked, also other scripts and keywords are working fine, but only FOR has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because user is using RIDE 1.7.4 to edit the test suites. It was not mentioned explicitly, but the error messages and from the pip list we can deduce that.

(Hima Manae, next time you should describe clearly the problem, like in "I using RIDE and getting the error ...")

We have several warnings on this issue, on RIDE Release Notes (from Help>Release Notes) and README, and Wiki at [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/F.A.Q.#2-q-in-the-newest-versions-of-ride-174-and-with-robot-framework-312-when-i-edit-a-test-suite-having--for-then-when-is-executed-appears-the-following-error-for-loop-contains-no-keywords-how-to-fix-this).

In simple words the answer is:

RIDE Text Editor changes `: FOR` to `FOR` and user must add the missing `END`.

This will be the loop style for version 3.2

Comment: thank u for informing, i will note on this, but i have tried to add "END" keyword as mentioned in my script initially, but it did not work. im still getting "FOR is a reserved keyword". also i will try to upgrade my robot framework, thanks!

Comment: Hi all! i have upgraded my robotframework to 3.1.2 and it worked fine. Used the command: pip install --upgrade robotframework==3.1.2. Thanks to all for the support!